# Mouse back button not working in GUI applications running inside docker

Tags: linux, mouse, docker, xorg

I have an application running inside docker (using X). It's working well except for the fact that my mouse back/forward buttons are not working.

Using `xev | grep button` I can validate that mouse buttons 8 & 9 are detected inside docker when pressing the two buttons. They just don't seem to have an effect to any application.

How can I fix this? Surprisingly Google is of absolutely no help here.

Comment: It can see they're buttons 8 & 9, but it doesn't know what to do with that information. You need to install whatever interpreter is adding that functionality outside the VM. [Your setup isn't one I'm familiar with, but generally for VMs you either add it to the 'top level' ie the VM application, or to the client OS.

Comment: Answering my own question, this here solves the problem: https://askubuntu.com/a/101126/638296